# How did I do this?

Tags: discussion

I was trying to put a vote to close [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/32146/tuition-related-repayment-deduction) as a duplicate, and it was closed immediately with my single vote. I thought only mods can do that.... What gives?

Comment: Maybe you have accquired enough powers ;)

Comment: Your score probably permits a hold. Although I don't see that spelled out in the powers list. If this is the case, I encourage you to use your powers for good,not evil.

Comment: Because you're awesome and we trust you to make rational, well-informed decisions based on your level of experience on the site :) (something we should have been doing long ago, IMHO).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your expertise in the tag let's you mark dupes directly.

My understanding is you can close dupes with your single vote because of the trust you earned, but your vote is normal putting something on hold.

Found it:

> ### Users With Gold Tag Badges Can Unilaterally Mark as Duplicate
>
> A user who has the gold tag badge, (which requires at least 1000 score
> across 200 answers) can mark questions in that tag as duplicates using
> a single vote, similar to a moderator. The question must have had the
> tag in its original posting, and the target duplicate must have an
> answer. These users may also unilaterally reopen questions marked as
> duplicate in that tag, in cases where the question shouldn’t have been
> closed, or when there is a more appropriate or complete target
> question. When such a top user closes a question, a gold badge icon
> will be displayed after their name in the close reason message.

Here is the Meta post:

[Increase close vote weight for gold tag badge holders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212)

Comment: And when I went back to see the GOLD badge icon, the hover text indicates the reason :)

Comment: Oh ok, didn't know that, thanks... I'll be more careful now:)

Comment: @littleadv - They just announced it a couple days ago in the mod email.